# How can I set attributes for SOAP elements in Delphi?

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, attributes, delphi-2009

In a SOAP client request, the header needs this line:

```
<NS2:Header Name="Foo">Bar<NS2:Header>
```

So I wrote a class which has two string properties:

- the Content property - for the value of the element ("Bar")
- the Name property - for the value of the attribute ("Foo")

The AS_ATTRIBUTE flag of the Name property should indicate that it is an XML "attribute".

```
   Header = class(TSoapHeader)
   private
     FContent: string;
     FName: string;
   published
     property Content: string read FContent write FContent;
     property Name: string read FName write FName stored AS_ATTRIBUTE;
   end;
```

and register with

```
   RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(Header, MY_URI);
   RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(Header, [xoLiteralParam, 
xoSimpleTypeWrapper]);
```

The xoLiteralTypWrapper option indicates that the class should only 'wrap' the value Content property in the  element and not add a nested  element for it.

For Name := "Foo" and Content := "Bar", this will be the result XML code in the SOAP request:

```
<NS2:Header Name="Foo">
   <Content xsi:type="xsd:string">Bar</Content>
</NS2:Header>
```

The attribute is in the correct place, but the content value is in a nested tag which should not be here. If I remove the Name property from the class definition the Content property will look nice as the element content, like this:

```
<NS2:Header>Bar</NS2:Header>
```

It looks like a conflict between the two requirements - if I have the 
attribute, I will not get the xoSimpleTypeWrapper style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this so this is a speculation. Try overriding ObjectToSOAP and SOAPToObject method. In the help file it says

> Override ObjectToSOAP to customize the
>   way your application converts a
>   TSOAPHeader descendant to its SOAP
>   representation.

Again, I haven't tried this on compiler, but it could look like the following:

```
function Header.ObjectToSOAP(RootNode, ParentNode: IXMLNode; 
  const ObjConverter: IObjConverter; const Name, URI: InvString; 
  ObjConvOpts: TObjectConvertOptions; out RefID: InvString): IXMLNode;  
begin 
  ObjConvOpts := ObjConvOpts + [ocoDontSerializeProps]; 
  Result := inherited ObjectToSOAP(RootNode, ParentNode, ObjConverter, Name, URI, ObjConvOpts, RefID); 
  Result.Text := FContent; 
  Result.Attributes['Name'] := FName;
end;
```